# Language switcher, redirect to current page with symfony

Tags: redirect, symfony1

What is the best way to do a language switcher in symfony that redirects to the same page in the chosen language? Jobeet simply redirects on the homepage.

Answer (score 1):

Something like so should do the trick:

```
<?php
class myActions extends sfActions
{
  public function executeLanguageSwitch(sfWebRequest $request)
  {
    $new_language = $request->getParameter('lang',false);
    $this->forward404unless($new_language);
    // You should probably insert stuff here check that the new culture passed in is valid
    $this->getUser()->setCulture($new_language);
    $this->redirect($request->getReferer());
    return sfView::HEADER_ONLY;
  }
}
```

Comment: this is always going to the index page not to my working action?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
<?php
class PageController extends Controller 
{
    public function changeLocaleAction(Request $request)
    {
        $locale = $request->get('_locale');
        $this->get('session')->set('_locale', $locale);
        $referer = $request->headers->get('referer');
        return new RedirectResponse($referer);
    }
}
```