# How to redirect to same page when change the user culture

Tags: php, redirect, symfony1

On symfony 1.2.8 i m stuck to redirect to same page when change the user culture. that mean if user change the culture from the some action its should go back to the same action instead of going to the `index` page i found a similer question on SF but its also going to the index page

[Language switcher, redirect to current page with symfony](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4359125/language-switcher-redirect-to-current-page-with-symfony)

**EDIT**
problem is my request coming from out of the symfony actually from another index file so i cant use $this->redirect($request->getReferer());

Comment: Not a perfect way, but you could use AJAX to change the language and then refresh the page

Comment: I think forcing a redirect to the homepage when the user changes the language is a very **very** bad UX choice. I don't understand why on [the jobeet tutorial](http://symfony.com/blog/jobeet-day-19-internationalization-and-localization) it is done this way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to redirect to referer.

```
//actions
$this->redirect($request->getReferer());
```

You can also append current page url as a parameter to user culture change url.

Comment: problem is my request coming from out of the symfony actually from another index file so i cant use $this->redirect($request->getReferer());

Comment: In symfony 2.x you can get the referer like this: $request->headers->get('referer');

Comment: On Symfony >= 2.4, You can do `return $this->redirect($request->getUri());` and get `$request` by passing it in method argument (to avoid doing $requestStack->getMasterRequest())

Answer (score 1):

I took [this tutorial](http://symfony.com/blog/jobeet-day-19-internationalization-and-localization) (jobeet about i18n) and modified the `executeChangeLanguage` function like this:

```
public function executeChangeLanguage(sfWebRequest $request)
  {
    $form = new sfFormLanguage(
        $this->getUser(),
        array('languages' => array('en', 'fr'))
    );

    $form->process($request);

    // added
    $url = $request->getReferer();
    $newUrl = $url;
    if ($request->getParameter('language') == 'fr') {
    $newUrl = str_replace('.com/en', '.com/fr', $url);
    }
    if ($request->getParameter('language') == 'en') {
    $newUrl = str_replace('.com/fr', '.com/en', $url);
    }
    return $this->redirect($newUrl);

    // old return
    // return $this->redirect('localized_homepage');
  }
```

This is dirty hack, but it worked for me.